# Amazon storage gateway how do you get the storage usage without using CloudWatch (from the Storage Gateway Volume Page)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, usage

I can't find where to get the volume usage (used space) in the Storage Gateway Volume page.

I don't want to use CloudWatch to have the information, there should be a way to add the column "Used space" in the Volume view? If I cannot check my data usage other than monitoring the iSCSI Target I won't use the product!

Comment: It's S3 backed, and S3 historically has been poor at showing space used by a bucket. Easiest way is to go into the bucket, select a folder, choose delete, and it'll show you. You can also look at the properties of the source device, but that won't help much for gateway cached.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't obtain the required info directly from AWS Storage Gateway UI. You'll need to use either AWS CLI or applications that are specifically aware of the back-end storage, such as Bucket Explorer, S3 Browser, Veeam + StarWind Cloud VTL, etc.

Comment: So it is badly designed or it is a business decision so you cannot know exactly how much data you're using, I won't be using the technology too much waste of time managing it !

Comment: Get somebody who actually reports you amount of consumed storage. Pretty much all referenced 3rd party software packages do that.